# Stack service containers dynamic hostname

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am migrating away from Docker Cloud to pure Docker Swarm setup. One thing that I am missing is the nice way of how the containers got the hostname set as **$SERVICE_NAME-$SLOT_NUMBER**.

Is it possible to dynamically set the hostname/container name in a swarm stack service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your stack/compose file, use this format:

```
services:
  thaservice:
    ...
    hostname: "{{.Service.Name}}-{{.Task.Slot}}"
```

Link to documentation for available template variables: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#create-services-using-templates