# Request from a container by host name on the same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a GET/POST request by **hostname** like `http:://super.localhost` instead of container name.

My `super.localhost` (nginx container) website available from *internet browser*, but from php container I can't make curl GET request (connection refused). Only by container name works.
PHP script has 100+ hosts by CURL all of them on nginx container.

`> CURL -i nginx` is works. `> CURL -i super.localhost` doesn't work. Any ideas hot to reach the response?

Everything on the one network. Ports for nginx 80:80

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        container_name: webshop-nginx
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./nginx/nginx.docker
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/app
            - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
        networks:
            - local
```

Comment: Seems this solution will work for you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719949/stack-service-containers-dynamic-hostname

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `hostname` configuration option in your compose file, like this example:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        container_name: nginx-1
        hostname: nginx-1
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
    nginx2:
        image: nginx
        container_name: nginx-2
        hostname: super.localhost
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
```

So, when in the `nginx-1` container you make `curl -i http://super.localhost/index.html` you can reach the `nginx-2` container.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this case too. It's going only if you have a few servers, then you can bind them by different service-hosts. But it's not appropriate case if you have dynamic host. `host1.local`, `host2.local`, ... `host9999.local`

Answer (score 0):

Actually for available hosts from inside of container need to use the [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases)

Aliases need to add in web server service of `docker-compose.yml`

```
   networks:
        local:
            aliases:
                - host1.localhost
                - host2.localhost
                - host3.localhost
```